# Drop Index com variavel SQL

Tags: sql, query, table

Sou um inexperiente gafanhoto e estou em busca de fazer um script automático para mim. Este script criei em batch e consigo ir sem problemas até a instalação do `SQL`, restauração da base de dados e execução de algumas Querys.

O meu problema é que meu segundo passo exige que eu exclua Indexes e Rowguide. Bom, o meu problema pior é que o indice é mutavel, então nunca tera o mesmo nome (pelo que me parece)

Então criei algo mais ou menos assim

```
Declare @indexeee varchar(50) =(select i.name from sys.indexes i
inner join sys.tables t
on i.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'Colecao'
and i.name like '%MSm%')

select @indexeee
```

Retorno

> MSmerge_index_1662628966

Perfeito para o que eu preciso, pois é este index que preciso excluir depois o rowguide vinculado a ele. mas nao consigo funcionar como script linux (onde tenho um pouco mais de experiencia) ou batch windows (que cresci com eles)

"COMANDOCITADOACIMA"

```
DROP INDEX @indexeee
    ON pdv.produto.colecao;  
GO
```

> Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 8 Sintaxe incorreta próxima a
>   '@indexeee'.

Ao colocar o mouse em cima da Indexeee temos:

> Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '@indexeee'. Esperando '.', 'ID', ou
>   QUOTE_ID.

Se possivel poder explicar a resposta, pois eu ainda nao sei muito de `SQL`, me mantendo basicamente no Select e inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Execute conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 'DROP INDEX ' + @indexeee + ' ON pdv.produto.colecao';
```